# Is it possible to spawn a local server in browserified web application

Tags: javascript, express, browser, server, browserify

I'm currently try to run my electron application into a browser.

To do so, I'm using browserify.
The main issue is that I use a proxy to treat some data between my video stream client and my [ipfs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System) endpoints.
The proxy is made with the node module express but it appears that you can't use it in a browser.

I've checked for some alternative modules, but the problem is apparently not the module but the fact to spawn a server in the browser itself.
Here is the last reference I found that confirms the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066279/how-to-create-http-server-in-browser-using-javascript):

Here is the error I get from the browser:

```
login-bundle.js:73697 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (login-bundle.js:73697)
    at Object.261../utils (login-bundle.js:74799)
    at o (login-bundle.js:1)
    at login-bundle.js:1
    at Object.257../application (login-bundle.js:72936)
    at o (login-bundle.js:1)
    at login-bundle.js:1
    at Object.255../lib/express (login-bundle.js:72264)
    at o (login-bundle.js:1)
    at login-bundle.js:1
```

refering to the following code:

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype)
```

where `ServerResponse` is undefined

That is why I found out that it was incompatible with the browser

I would like to know if anyone knows any solution to spawn a server into my browserified application.

Comment: why do you want to spawn a server in a client application? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a video media player pointing on my proxy (the server). The proxy is used to encrypt/decrypt data from a url endpoint.